# Firebase deploy node js functions error "Functions did not deploy properly."

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, firebase

estoy tratando de hacer un deploy de mi aplicacion node en firebase functions, espero que alguien sepa como resolver esto ya que estoy hace dias, hago el firebase init me lo hace bien, me crea la carpeta functions, luego accedo a ella, y en mi index.js de functions tengo lo siguiente:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const Express = require("express");
const app = Express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const Bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const { uploadArticulos } = require('./tools/libs/storageArticulos');

//CONFIGURACION DE APLICACION
require("dotenv").config({
    path: "./.env"
});

//MIDDLEWARES
app.use(Express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(Express.json());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(Bodyparser.json({limit: "2mb"}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(Express.static('public'));
app.use(uploadArticulos.any());

//RUTAS 
//ESTO PERMITE PARA QUE NO IMPORTEMOS TODOS LOS ARCHIVOS DE LA CARPETA ROUTES, VA A LEER EL QUE SELECCIONEMOS
//A LA HORA DE LLAMARLO POR URL, HACER LO MISOM PARA LAS DEMAS CARPETAS.
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.send("FUNCIONO TOKO OKEY PERRO");
});

readdirSync("./routes").map((r) => {
    app.use("/api", require("./routes/" + r));
});

//PUERTO
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor corriendo en : ${port}`);
});

exports.appBackend = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Ahora bien , cuando quiero ejecutar firebase deploy --only functions en mi cmd, me arroja el siguiente error: "Functions did not deploy properly." , alguno sabe por que puede ser ? Desde ya muchas gracias  !

Comment: Amigo encontré esto que estoy probando, dime si te sirve, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67695957/error-functions-did-not-deploy-properly-delete-callable-function

Comment: Gracias @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales , al final era un problema que tenia con una configuracion de firebase. El resto de las funciones estaban bien, muchas gracias por la ayuda ! (: